# Need help with SQL Server configuration

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation

I was planning to buy the SQL Server 2012 standard edition for developing reports and SSIS packages. My company does not have a client-server architecture and the developers are working on their individual machines connected through the Lan.

I am really confused now on how should I configure the installation so that the developers will be able to connect to the server. Do I need to buy an individual licence for each machine (which is quite costly). Is there any alternative to the same?

I have searched the internet for similar solutions but was unable to find any. Please guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012 R2** version - just **2012** - corrected

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "my company does not have a client-server architecture".

Comment: @spaghettidba what I mean is that we do not have a windows server that each individual developer can access from there machine. Basically every developer have a machine with windows 7 installed on it. They can share the files but not the applications. Hope I made some sense, Let me know if more explanation is needed.

Comment: @marc_s I was just going through the quotes that were given to me by a Microsoft vendor . He mentioned the product https://www.cdw.com/shop/products/Microsoft-Windows-Server-2012-R2-Standard-license/3178215.aspx
I searched the web and found that no official announcement was made. How can I be sure that I am not tricked into buying a false product.

Comment: @ankitsuhail: there is a **Windows Server** 2012 R2 - but no SQL Server **2012 R2** - so it's not quite clear which product he was referring to ...

Answer (score 2):

Install the database engine on the server, then Management Studio on each developer's machine.

Assuming they have permissions, the developers can then use Management Studio to connect to the database on the server.

Because Management Studio is free, you only need to ensure the server-based SQL Server instance is licensed.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to do, one of these combinations will be the right choice for you:

- Choose a development model:

  **1. Central Development Server**
   Install a SQL Server instance on a server machine. Developers will connect to the instance using the
  client tools (SQL Server Management Studio - SQL Server Data Tools
  BI) installed on their machines.

  **2. Local Development Server**
   Install an instance of SQL Server on each developer's machine. Each developer will work on his own copy of
  the database.
- Choose an edition:

  **A. Developer Edition**
   It's a special edition of SQL Server targeted for development. Basically it has all the features available
  in Enterprise Edition, but it's not licensed for production use. You
  have to buy 1 license for each developer connecting to it (it's
  around $60 each).

  **B. Standard Edition**
   It's a good choice when
  you want to make sure that no Enterprise-only feature gets used
  during develpment work when you're targeting Standard Edition in
  production. With an MSDN subscription, you can use Standard Edition for development/test purposes with no additional
  charges (except the subscription, of course). Without a subscription, you have to buy licenses (either core-based or CAL-based).

  **C. Express Edition**
   It's a free edition of SQL Server, with some limitations on the resources (1GB of RAM, 1 CPU) and the
  database size (10GB at most). Usually it's enough for development
  purposes, if the database fits in 10GB.

Answer (score 2):

No need to buy individual licence for each machine. you just install your licence SQL server 2012 in server PC and install SQL server management studio to all your client PC and through (IP,Port ) able to connect to server. it's depend on your security of your environment. how you want to give security privilege to client user & also outside environment.

By default SQL server Browser listening port 1433 and UDP 1434 . If you have System Administrator & Network Administrator in your environment then consult with them. Then can also set some other port apart from 1433 (if your organization want as per their policy).

It's also depend on your server configuration environment. If you have install SQL server 2012 in domain environment with forest then you have to provide privilege to your client user.

If you want to some SQL server 2012 feature like (Replication,AlwaysOn Availability Group, WSFC Cluster etc)then I would suggest you in place of 
SQL Server 2012 standard edition you have to buy SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition.

for ref http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feWhenature/-to-consider-SQL-Server-Enterprise-Edition and for software and hardware requirement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.110).aspx